# set row grouping programatically in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I tried setting rowGrouping to a specific column as shown below:

```
    columnDefs[index]["rowGroup"] = true;
    this.setState({ columnDefs: columnDefs });
    params.api.setColumnDefs(columnDefs);
```

The grid is getting rerendered but the row grouping is not getting set. Is there any other ag-grid api to set the row groups manually(just like columnApi.setColumnVisible to hide/show a specific column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your updated columnDefs is not being applied to the grid.

Setting your columnDef to an empty array or creating a new ColumnDef object altogether should solve this.

```
  gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs([]);
  gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(newColDefs);
```